# rewrite script to use wp_remote_get instead of file_get_contents_curl

Tags: wp-remote-get

I have a script that pulls the facebook likes via facebook graph and writes them in my DB. However it uses file_get_contents_curl for the request and this is causing problems, so I'd like to use the wp_remote_get() command. I've tried to change it but somehow I can't do it (I don't really have PHP knowledge).

Here's the part of the script:

```
foreach($posts as $post)
    {

        $fb = json_decode(file_get_contents_curl('http://graph.facebook.com/?id='.get_permalink($post->ID)));
        if( !isset( $fb->likes) && isset($fb->shares) )
        {
            $fb->likes = $fb->shares;
        }
        //$fb->likes = isset($fb->likes) ? $fb->likes : 0;
        $myfblikes = sprintf("%04s", (int)$fb->likes);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'fb_likes', $myfblikes);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foreach( $posts as $post )
{
    $url      = sprintf( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=%s', get_permalink( $post->ID ) );
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url,  array( 'timeout' => 15 ) );


    if( ! is_wp_error( $response ) 
        && isset( $response['response']['code'] )        
        && 200 === $response['response']['code'] )
    {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $fb   = json_decode( $body );

        if( ! isset( $fb->likes ) && isset( $fb->shares ) )
        {
            $fb->likes = $fb->shares;
        }

        if( isset( $fb->likes ) )
        {
            $myfblikes = sprintf( '%04s', (int) $fb->likes );
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fb_likes', $myfblikes );
       }
    }
}
```

where we can use `wp_remote_retrieve_body()` to get the response body of `wp_remote_get()`.

Comment: `wp_remote_retrieve_body` only does two things: check for `is_wp_error` and check `! isset( $response['body']`.  Since you're already checking `is_wp_error` in your own code might as well just check if `$response['body']` is set instead of using `wp_remote_retrieve_body`.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_remote_get` returns an array, not a string. So,

```
foreach($posts as $post) {

    // get remote document as JSON
    $json = wp_remote_get( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . get_permalink($post->ID) );

    // check for WP_Error
    if(is_wp_error($json))
        return false;

    // Decode JSON and get document body as associative array
    $fbData = json_decode($json['body'], true);

    // return (numeric) array value
    return intval($fbData['likes']);
}
```

I'm not sure about `get_permalink($post->ID)` part. That's OK only if you have a FB page for each post.

Answer (score 0):

Just change one function with the other. This requires also to change the way you are using `json_decode()` because `wp_remote_get()` returns an array and `json_decode()` requires a string.

```
foreach($posts as $post) {

    $fb = wp_remote_get( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) );

    if( ! is_wp_error( $fb ) ) {

        $body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $fb ) );

        if( ! isset( $body->likes) && isset( $body->shares ) ) {
            $body->likes = $body->shares;
        }

        $myfblikes = sprintf( "%04s", (int) $body->likes );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fb_likes', $myfblikes );
    }
}
```

Comment: that was the frist thing I tried. It gives me this error `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /usr/www/users/toaste/zitate/wp-content/plugins/order_posts_by_social/order_posts_by_social.php on line 151` - line 151 is the line I replaced the command btw

Comment: That is because you are passing an array to `json_decode()`, not a string. This error is not related with the `wp_remote_get()` itself, it is related with its returned value and the way you are using `json_decode()`. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, try out this

```
 $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.html' );
if( is_array($response) ) {
  $header = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
  $body = $response['body']; // use the content
}
echo $body; // to print content
```