# How to use wp_remote_get in place of file_get_contents?

Tags: wp-remote-get

I am trying to implement this plugin( http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/creating-a-simple-backuprestore-settings-feature/ ) with my theme. Everything's working great. but the problem is in a wordpress environment I cannot use `file_get_contents`. I have to use `wp_remote_get` or `wp_remote_post`. I tried various methods to implement those. But its not working. Can you anyone help me replace the file_get_contents with wordpress equivalent? 
Thanks.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: I/E Option
Plugin URI: http://wp.tutsplus.com/
Description: This is a sample plugin with backup and restore options feature.
Author: Lee Pham
Version: 1.0
Author URI: https://twitter.com/leephamj
*/
ob_start();
function register_ie_option() {
    add_menu_page('IE Option Page', 'IE Option', 'activate_plugins', 'ie-option', 'ie_option_page', '');    
    add_submenu_page('ie-option', 'Import', 'Import', 'activate_plugins', 'ie-import-option', 'ie_import_option_page');
    add_submenu_page('ie-option', 'Export', 'Export', 'activate_plugins', 'ie-export-option', 'ie_export_option_page'); 
}

/*  
 *  Main page
 */
function ie_option_page() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"><br /></div>
        <h2>Backup & Restore </h2>
        <p>This is only a sample plugin that demonstrate how to create a simple import/export feature for your own templates or plugins.</p>
        <p>Hope it useful for you!</p>
        <p>Get in touch with me:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>E-mail: leephamj@gmail.com</li>
            <li>Twitter: <a href="http://twitter.com/leephamj">@leephamj</a></li>
            <li>Facebook: <a href="http://facebook.com/tungchen93">Lee Pham</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php   
}

/*  
 *  Import feature
 */
function ie_import_option_page() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"><br /></div>
        <h2>Import</h2>
        <?php
            if (isset($_FILES['import']) && check_admin_referer('ie-import')) {
                if ($_FILES['import']['error'] > 0) 
                    wp_die("Error happens");        
                else {
                    $file_name = $_FILES['import']['name'];
                    $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $file_name)));
                    $file_size = $_FILES['import']['size'];
                    if (($file_ext == "json") && ($file_size < 500000)) {
                        $encode_options = file_get_contents($_FILES['import']['tmp_name']);
                        $options = json_decode($encode_options, true);
                        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                            update_option($key, $value);    
                        }
                        echo "<div class='updated'><p>All options are restored successfully.</p></div>";
                    }   
                    else 
                        echo "<div class='error'><p>Invalid file or file size too big.</p></div>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        <p>Click Browse button and choose a json file that you backup before.</p>
        <p>Press Restore button, Wordpress do the rest for you.</p>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <p class="submit">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('ie-import'); ?>
                <input type='file' name='import' />
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Restore'/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}

/*  
 *  Export feature
 */
function ie_export_option_page() {
    if (!isset($_POST['export'])) { 
?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"><br /></div>
            <h2>Export</h2>
            <p>When you click <tt>Backup all options</tt> button, system will generate a JSON file for you to save on your computer.</p>
            <p>This backup file contains all configution and setting options on our website. Note that it do <b>NOT</b> contain posts, pages, or any relevant data, just your all options.</p>
            <p>After exporting, you can either use the backup file to restore your settings on this site again or another Wordpress site.</p>
            <form method='post'>
            <p class="submit">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('ie-export'); ?>
                <input type='submit' name='export' value='Backup all options'/>
            </p>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php 
    } elseif (check_admin_referer('ie-export')) {

        $blogname = str_replace(" ", "", get_option('blogname'));
        $date = date("m-d-Y");
        $json_name = $blogname."-".$date; // Namming the filename will be generated.

        $options = get_alloptions(); // Get all options data, return array

        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $value = maybe_unserialize($value);
            $need_options[$key] = $value;
        }

        $json_file = json_encode($need_options); // Encode data into json data

        ob_clean();
        echo $json_file;
        header("Content-Type: text/json; charset=" . get_option( 'blog_charset'));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$json_name.json");
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_ie_option');
```

Comment: There was a similar question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114914/rewrite-script-to-use-wp-remote-get-instead-of-file-get-contents-curl) recently

Comment: Yes I saw that and I tried to implement it. But doesnt work :/

Comment: Can you provide any debug information on your current code? It looks like you are opening a local temp file, but not a remote file, so why do you want to use wp_remote_get()?

Comment: yes you are correct. I am trying to open local file. I thought wp_remote_get also opens local files. Do you have any idea what I should use instead of wp_remote_get then? Thanks.

Comment: `wp_remote_*` family of functions are for... well, _remote_ requests. They don't work with local file system. Why exactly can't you use `file_get_contents()`? This might be relevant for recommending alternative approach.

Comment: I am trying to upload my theme which uses the plugin, to wordpress theme repository which doesnt allow any themes that thas `file_get_contents` in it. Thanks.