# using wp_remote_get instead of file_get_contents

Tags: json, wp-remote-get

have run my theme through the Theme checker plugin and it seems upset about use of `file_get_contents` to get a json url. I've found posts saying i should use `wp_remote_get`. I'm currently decoding the url with the following:

```
$url = 'url' . $var;
$json =   file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
$output = json_decode($json,true);
```

The message I get from the Theme Checker is:

> WARNING: file_get_contents was found in the file.php possible file operations.

Is it just saying this because there is a function I could possibly use by wordpress or any other reasons? Also how would I use `wp_remote_get`. I tried a few variations, mostly replacing file_get_contents with `wp_remote_get` with no luck. Doesn't seem to decode the url at all.

Comment: [This question/answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114914/rewrite-script-to-use-wp-remote-get-instead-of-file-get-contents-curl/114918#114918) can help you

Comment: hi, thanks for that, did help, so assumed it was saying wp-Remote did all the decoding for me already? So did $url = 'url' . $var; $output = wp_remote_get( $url ); but did not work

Comment: You have to read again the link I posted. If you make `$output = wp_remote_get( $url );` the `$output` will be an array where you can access to `$output['headers']`, `$output['body']`. I think what you want is `$json = json_decode($output['body']);`

Comment: Don't use `json_decode($output['body']` instead use `wp_remote_retrieve_body( $output )`

Comment: Despite being closed as a duplicate this question is a lot better written and deals with the single issue of how to start using `wp_remote_get` in place of `file_get_contents` or `file_get_contents_curl` - and because the question is clearer, the answers are better and easier to understand.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to send a JSON response, then there's a set of functions for that. In case you need that for an AJAX callback:

- [`wp_remote_retrieve_response_message()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_retrieve_response_message)
- [`wp_remote_retrieve_response_code()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_retrieve_response_code)
- [`wp_send_json_success()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_send_json_success/)
- [`wp_send_json_error()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_send_json_error/)
- [`wp_send_json()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_send_json/)

Would finally be something like that:

```
$request  = wp_remote_get( 'http://example.com' );
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
if ( 
    'OK' !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response )
    OR 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response )
)
    wp_send_json_error( $response );

wp_send_json_success( $response );
```

Both `wp_send_json_success/_error()` functions are wrappers for `wp_send_json()`, which includes `wp_die()` at the end. So there's nothing else to do.

Keep in mind that 99% of all remote APIs are sending `200/OK` in case of errors. You'll still have to manually inspect the result and check for errors.

Answer (score 8):

Use [wp_remote_get()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_retrieve_body) in conjunction with [wp_remote_retrieve_body()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get)

Example

```
<?php
$request = wp_remote_get('http://example.com');
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
echo $response;
?>
```

Check the documentation for possible arguements

Comment: Hi, thanks, I seem to be able to echo out the whole thing but when I just try to get some certain values within the json file, lets say $response['companyname'] i Just get a '{'

Comment: If the body of a document is also a json file then use `json_encode()`

Comment: `wp_remote_retrieve_body` is good because it checks to make sure there are no errors and it also returns an empty string if $request['body'] is not set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_remote_get()` in the following way:

```
$url = 'url' . $var;
$request =   wp_remote_get($url);
// Get the body of the response
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
// Decode the json
$output = json_decode( $response );
```

`$output` now has what you want and now you can go ahead and do your stuff.

There is a also a series of tutorials on `wp_remote_get()`. Go through it, it will definitely help.

Link -- [Tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/a-look-at-the-wordpress-http-api-a-brief-survey-of-wp_remote_get/)

Hope it helps.