# How do I deliver posts based on user geolocation

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Im grabbing the users geolocation and saving it in $georegion

```
$geoPlugin_array = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );
$georegion  =  $geoPlugin_array['geoplugin_regionName'] ;
 echo $georegion . " :GEO REGION<br>";
```

I have a taxonomy called 'local-music' that stores city locations matching the $georegion and I'm trying to query it like this but doesn't seem to work

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'local-music',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $georegion ),
            )
        )
    );
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `file_get_contents` to make remote requests, use the `WP_HTTP` API or a library such as guzzle

Comment: Is there a reason I shouldn't use file_get_contents

Comment: A lot of servers disable it from making remote requests for security reasons, using the WordPress APIs allows plugins to interact, and the fallbacks WordPress provides ( e.g. Curl ) to be used. [See here for more information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115896/using-wp-remote-get-instead-of-file-get-contents)

Comment: Could this be the reason why my query not working?

Comment: In much the same way that paper walls make a terrible house, it does not prevent your query from working but it's rarely a good idea. Of particular note however, you make no attempt to check errors. That service shows `""` as my region here in the UK, which isn't handled by your code, nor are 404's, 500's, or network errors handled. You also make no attempt to define what you expect `$georegion` to be, is it a slug? "washington"? or a term ID? or a country code? This is ***very*** important but you gloss over it

Comment: I'm using www.geoplugin.com to get the geolocation. A few other people told me it doesn't work for them. Do you know of a better geo solution? As far as $georegion its a slug Im in new york so it echo's "New York". I was thinking of using latitude and longitude instead.

Comment: There is no bullet proof solution, in the past I've used the javascript geolocation API. Doing it server-side runs the risk that you may mis-locate someone and they can't access the correct page as your server thinks they're elsewhere or can't locate them. But at the very least validate the data you do receive for error codes and empty values.

Comment: Also keep in mind that people move, if I pull up your site on a plane/on holiday/while visiting a friend/in a car, I'm not going to get relevant results, especially if I'm google and google can only see the page for their data centres location

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good it is the value in $georegion being what looks like a name / text string, and your query comparing it against the ID of the local-music terms.

If the $georegion value matches the slug of the taxonomy terms, then changing ID to slug might fix your problem, in reality, you'll probably need to do some massaging to get direct matches, depending on how everything is set up on your end - but to answer your question, I think using the ID field is the root of your problem right now.

Comment: Changing ID to slug did not work